# Loading Bot Functions On Start

Tags: javascript, object, discord.js

I have a few functions that I would like to be able to access from anywhere on my Discord Bot, and I have been trying for a few hours on exporting all the functions, but I am stuck on how to actually give them a name.

```js
    async loadFunctions() {
        return glob(`${this.directory}Functions/*.js`).then(functions => { // Returns array of all files
            functions.forEach((m) => {
                const { name } = path.parse(m); // Takes the name of each file
                const File = require(m); // This takes the class from the file
                this.client.functions./* the 'name' variable */ = new File(this); // Create the function
            });
        });
    }
```

I believe my code is wrong and will not work how I want it to, but I am not sure what I should be doing instead.
If I just do `this.client.functions = new File(this)`
then it will work, and I can access the function and it functions as expected. However, since it is in a `forEach`, each type it loops, it overwrites the name since it is the same, I thought it would be something like `this.client.functions[name]` but that was also wrong. Any help appreciated!

Comment: `this.client.functions[name]` should work. What was wrong with it?

Comment: Says `TypeError: Cannot set property 'pagination' of undefined`
pagination being the first function in the folder (but if I don't put [name], the function is loaded and can be accessed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.client.functions[name]` should work. The reason you're receiving `TypeError: Cannot set property 'pagination' of undefined` is that `this.client.functions` is undefined. You need to make sure it's initialised to an empty object (`{}`) before you try to add a new property to it:

```js
async loadFunctions() {
  this.client.functions = {};

  return glob(`${this.directory}Functions/*.js`).then((functions) => {
    functions.forEach((m) => {
      const { name } = path.parse(m);
      const File = require(m);
      this.client.functions[name] = new File(this);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: This now says `TypeError: this.client.functions.pagination is not a function`
If I do `this.client.functions.pagination` then I can see it exists, without the object or [name] the function works.

Comment: How does your `pagination` file looks like?

Comment: Isn't `this.client.functions.pagination.pagination` the function/method? `this.client.functions.pagination` is an object created using `new File()`. Your `Pagination` class has the `pagination` method.

Comment: Does all your classes have a single method and nothing else? Are you sure you need classes? Why don't you just export a single function?

Comment: It is! Wow thank you, any way to making it `this.client.functions.pagination` though? - Not all of them only have one method

Comment: You're welcome. Probably, a really hacky way would be using `this.client.functions[name] = new File(this)[name.toLowerCase()];` but it's error-prone and would only work with methods that have the same name as the classes themselves...